# Share photos not works when user is previously logged Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sharer

I have this logic

```
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) { 
    NSLog(@"has granted!");
    [self sharePhotoWithFBSDK:title andImage:image]; //for logged users
} else {
    FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"response logInWithPublishPermissions!!! %@",error);
       if (!error) {
           [self sharePhotoWithFBSDK:title andImage:image]; //Non logged users
       }
    }];
}

- (void)sharePhotoWithFBSDK:(NSString *)title andImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    FBSDKSharePhoto *sharePhoto = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    sharePhoto.caption = title;
    sharePhoto.image = image;

    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
    content.photos = @[sharePhoto];

    [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
}
```

When the user is logged into facebook previously, the request to share a photo is lost in limbo. Entering the library I realized that enters this function `_sharePhotoContent`y dies right in this line`FBSDKGraphRequestHandler completionHandler = ^ (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection * connection, id result, NSError * error) {`

> i can not think of anything reasonable that may be causing this occurs.

I only know that when I try to do the same with a user without session (for the else) works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I was calling share logic into

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^{

});
```

So, need calling in main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self sharePhotoWithFBSDK:title andImage:image];
});
```